# How can I compare dates using Python?

Tags: python

If I have a hard coded date, how can I compare it to a date that is given by the user?

I want to eventually compare a persons birthday to see how old they are. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: time.strptime is your friend ...

Comment: i dont think i learned that yet. im in a intro python class, and we have to use strings

Comment: `time.strptime` uses strings. Check it out in the documentation.

Comment: somehow I dont think you are expected to evaluate the strings manually ... you need to convert them to a comparable value such as a `time` object or a `datetime` object ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use Python's standard library [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module to parse and convert the "date given by the user" to a `datetime.date` instance and then subtract that from the current date, `datetime.date.today()`. For example:

```
>>> birthdate_str = raw_input('Enter your birthday (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
Enter your birthday (yyyy-mm-dd): 1981-08-04
>>> birthdatetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(birthdate_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> birthdate = birthdatetime.date()  # convert from datetime to just date
>>> age = datetime.date.today() - birthdate
>>> age
datetime.timedelta(11397)
```

`age` is a `datetime.timedelta` instance, and the 11397 is their age in days (available directly via `age.days`).

To get their age in years, you could do something like this:

```
>>> int(age.days / 365.24)
31
```